# what is the most performant way to delete elements from a List<T> in c# while doing a foreach?

Tags: c#

i want to know what is the best way to delete elements from a List in c# while doing a foreach.

here is a code sample. first i create a list with some elements and then delte one:

```
List<int> foo = new List<int>();
foo.Add(1);
foo.Add(2);
foo.Add(3);
foreach (int i in foo)
{
    if (i==2)
    {
        foo.Remove(i);
    }
}
```

when i run this, i get a `InvalidOperationException` but how to solve this with a performant way?

Comment: So instead of *performant,* you should instead ask what is *correct.* After solving this puzzle, *then* worry about if it is performant.

Comment: I agree with @AnthonyPegram. You also need to decide if you are memory constrained or processor constrained when you talk about performance - the answer will be different each way.

Comment: Your question is "I want to drill a hole in this wall; what's the fastest way to do that with a hammer?" The fastest way is to *not use a hammer in the first place*. The foreach loop is not the right tool for the job; asking how to use the wrong tool to solve the problem more quickly is not a productive question to ask.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you must remove entries while enumerating, walk the list in backward direction, and remove items that you need to remove.

```
for (var i = foo.Count-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    if (MustBeRemoved(foo[i])) {
        foo.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Note that this is *not* required in case of your post, where you know the values that need to be removed.

Comment: `foo.RemoveAll(MustBeRemoved)` would be more performant if many elements need to be removed.

Comment: Note: this code does not enumerate the list. It's using an index variable, not an enumerator. Editing a list while enumerating it is not allowed and will result in an exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Answer (score 9):

```
foo.RemoveAll(x => x == 2);
```

In case you decide not to use for and foreach ;)

Comment: If your .NET version supports it, I would use this above the "looping backwards through the array" method. It's cleaner, less code, more readable and less error prone.

Answer (score 7):

I assume your actual use case is more complicated than what you have laid out. So let's assume you actually have some condition at play that applies to each element and that multiple elements can satisfy. We'll call that a **predicate**.

`List<T>` exposes a `RemoveAll` method that allows you to supply a predicate. Any item that matches that predicate is then removed. For example

```
Func<int, bool> isEven = i => i % 2 == 0;
List<int> ints = ...
ints.RemoveAll(item => isEven(item));
// ints will only contain odd numbers
```

Other approaches to consider would be walking over the list backwards in a `for` loop and removing by index, building a second list containing the items to delete, and then in a second loop *over the second list*, remove items from the first. Or you could just write a query to construct a *new* sequence containing the items that you wish to keep.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need a loop?

```
foo.Remove(2);
```

Comment: I'm going to assume he simplified his example too much :)

Comment: I'm guessing he's just giving a grossly simplified example.

Comment: its a very simple example, in the real code its must more complex. so this dont work

Comment: @ThomasLevesque the real code looks like `foo.RemoveAll(i => i == 2);`.  The example you gave doesn't compile because `List<T>.RemoveAll` has no overload accepting a `T` parameter.

Comment: @phoog, that's not what I wrote, someone else edited my answer... I'll roll it back to how it was before.

Comment: @Joey, please refrain from editing other people's answers except for fixing typos or formatting. I wrote what I intended to write, don't try to second guess me...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque it's a dangerous world, the world of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to iterate backwards using a simple `for` loop.

```
for(int i = foo.Count-1; i>=0; i--)
    if(foo[i]==2) foo.RemoveAt(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

change your foreach as below

```
foreach (int i in new List<int>(foo))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove arbitrary elements, and not just one, you can use `RemoveAll` and specify a predicate:

```
foo.RemoveAll(element => (element == 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the items that you want to remove to a temporary list, then remove them after the loop:

```
List<int> foo = new List<int>();
foo.Add(1);
foo.Add(2);
foo.Add(3);

List<int> remove = new List<int>();

foreach (int i in foo) {
  if (i==2) {
    remove.Add(i);
  }
}

foreach (int i in remove) {
  foo.Remove(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit a list while you're iterating it.

Consider:

```
List<int> foo;
int[] bar = foo.ToArray();

foreach(int i in bar)
{
    if (i == 2)
    {
        foo.Remove(i);
    }
}
```

But beware: you should walk this list backwards, because removing an item from the foo list will mean the bar list no longer aligns with it. (If you don't walk backwards, you'll have to keep track of the count of removals and adjust the index passed to the remove call!)